# Different Image Sizes in Force-Directed Images and Labels Layout in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a simple problem which I'm not able to solve. So I implemented the Force-Directed Layout in d3js according like it is shown [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642). However now the images I want to include in the graph are of different sizes. So I wrote a function *imagesize* that determines the dimensions of theses images. However, the problem is that on the first start of layout the images are not shown. If I reload it then it works perfectly. I guess the problem is the onload function, but I dont know how else I can get the dimensions.

You can find the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/riasc/zh677re5/24/). So what I was writing about you can find in line 62 - 67.

```
.attr("width", function(d) { 
    return imagesize("https://github.com/favicon.ico")[0];
})
.attr("height", function(d) { 
    return imagesize("https://github.com/favicon.ico")[1];
});
```

and imagesize

```
function imagesize(link) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = link;
    return [img.width, img.width];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITS**

Stash the width and height in the datum for each node and then use it when you draw the lines.  See code updates below:

---

You aren't handling the asynchronous load of the image.  Further, you can streamline this a bit by using a `.each`:

```
appended.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
  .attr("x", "-8px")
  .attr("y", "-8px")
  .each(imagesize); //<-- call this for each image

function imagesize(d) {
  var self = d3.select(this); //<-- this is the svg image
  function loaded() { //<-- when your img is finished loading set width/height
    d.width = img.width; //<-- stash width/height in each node
    d.height = img.height;
    self.attr('width', d.width);
    self.attr('height', d.height);
  }
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = self.attr('href'); //<-- you can get this from the svg image
  if (img.complete) {
    loaded(); //<-- is to already done
  } else {
    img.addEventListener('load', loaded); //<-- callback after loading
    img.addEventListener('error', function() {
        alert('error');
    })
  }
}
```

---

When drawing lines:

```
force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { 
    // draw line with width of node
    // since width is set async, protect against null values
    return d.source.x + (d.source.width ? d.source.width/2 : 0); 
  })
```

---

Full code:

```js
var width = 300, height = 300;
  var radius = 5;

 var svg = d3.select('#main')
   .append("svg")
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("width", width);
  
  var nodes = [], links = [];
  
  var force = d3.layout.force()
   .charge(-350)
    .linkDistance(50)
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
   .size([height, width]);
    
 var node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
      link = svg.selectAll('.link');
      
  var drag = force.drag().on("dragstart", dragstart);
  
  nodes.push({id: 0, name:"zero"});
  nodes.push({id: 1, name:"one"});
  
  links.push({source: 0, target: 1});
  update();
  
  function update() {
   // add reference to index of nodes
    var edges = [];
    links.forEach(function(e){
     var sourcenode = nodes.filter(function(n) { 
      return n.id === e.source; 
     })[0];
    
     var targetnode = nodes.filter(function(n) { 
      return n.id === e.target; 
     })[0];
     edges.push({source: sourcenode, target: targetnode});
    });
    
    links = edges;
    
    var link = svg.selectAll("line.link")
                    .data(links, function(d) { 
                     return d.source.id + '-' + d.target.id; 
                    });

    link.enter().insert("line").attr("class", "link").style("stroke","black");
    link.exit().remove();

    node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) {return d.id;});
    node.exit().remove();

    var appended = node.enter().append("g").call(drag);

    appended.append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
      .attr("x", "-8px")
      .attr("y", "-8px")
      .each(imagesize);
      
    appended
     //.on("dblclick", dblclick)
      .on("contextmenu", dragend);

    appended.append("text")
   .attr("dx", "12")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
      
  force.on("tick", function() {
     link.attr("x1", function(d) { 
       return d.source.x + (d.source.width ? d.source.width/2 : 0); 
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { 
       return d.source.y + (d.source.height ? d.source.height/2 : 0); 
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { 
       return d.target.x + (d.target.width ? d.target.width/2 : 0);
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { 
       return d.target.y + (d.target.height ? d.target.height/2 : 0); 
      });

      node.attr("transform", function(d) {
       var x = Math.max(radius, 
         Math.min($('svg').attr('width')  - radius, d.x));
        var y = Math.max(radius, 
         Math.min($('svg').attr('height') - radius, d.y));
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      });
     });
    force.start();
  }
  
  function dragstart(d) {
   d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
  }

  function dragend(d) {
   d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
  }
  

function imagesize(d) {
 var self = d3.select(this);
  function loaded() {
    d.width = img.width;
    d.height = img.height;
    self.attr('width', d.width);
    self.attr('height', d.height);
  }
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = self.attr('href');
  if (img.complete) {
    loaded();
  } else {
    img.addEventListener('load', loaded)
    img.addEventListener('error', function() {
        alert('error');
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="main"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That is obviously exactly what I need. Awesome. I need to check this asynchronous load. Is there also a way to place the endpoints of the line directly in the center of the image. Like attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x + width/2;}) ?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again. Big time.